# How to sort one column and add values later

Tags: sorting, unix

I would to first sort a specific column, which I do using `sort -k2 <file>`. Then, after it is sorted using the values from the second column, I would like to add all the values from column 1 , delete duplicates, and keep the value from column 1.

Example:

```
2 AAAAAA
3 BBBBBB
1 AAAAAA
2 BBBBBB
1 CCCCCC
```

`sort -k2 <file>` does this:

```
2 AAAAAA
1 AAAAAA
3 BBBBBB
2 BBBBBB
1 CCCCCC
```

I know `uniq -c` will removes duplicates and outputs how many times it occurred, however I don't want to know how many times it occurred, I just need column 1 to be added and displayed. So that I would get:

```
3 AAAAAA
5 BBBBBB
1 CCCCCC
```

Comment: Hi Vaxin, your question is not clear. From the result, I understand you want to sum column 1 grouping on column 2. Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

`-c` is your enemy. You explicitly asked for the count . Here is my suggestion:

```
sort -k2 <file>| uniq -f1 file2
```

which gives me

```
cat file2
1 AAAAAA
2 BBBBBB
1 CCCCCC
```

If you want only column 2 in file, then use `awk`

```
sort -k2 <file>| uniq -f1 |awk '{print $2}' > file2
```

leading to

```
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
```

### Now I got it at last.

.... But if you want to sum in column 1, then just use `awk` ... Of course you could not make a grouped count with uniq...

```
awk '{array[$2]+=$1} END  { for (i in array) {print  array[i], i}}' file  |sort -k2
```

which leads to your solution (even if I sorted afterwards):

```
3 AAAAAA
5 BBBBBB
1 CCCCCC
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution using two for loops:

The first loop loops over all different strings in the file (test.txt), for each one we find all the numbers in the original file, and add them in the second loop. After adding all numbers we echo the total, and the string.

```
for chars in `sort -k2 test.txt | uniq -f 1 | cut -d' ' -f 2 `;
do
    total=0;
    for nr in `grep $a test.txt | cut -d' ' -f 1`;
    do
        total=$(($total+$nr));
    done;

    echo $total $chars
done
```